# Multiple charts in background ChartJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, chart.js

Im having an issue when i generate one chart with chart.js, but when i generate another chart  from the menu in the same page, it generates the chart, but when i move the move over the chart it changes to previous one.

**UPDATE**

After some research in chart.js documentation found an method that clear the chart data, ive applied to the controller before getting new data, unfortunately continues to get the previous charts in background when mouse over the chart ive made a console log of the array that contains the values, and that is updated with the data of the most recent request.

Code from the controller

```
 $scope.getChart = function (report) {
 $scope.modalLabels = [];
 $scope.data = {values: ([])}; //Array that contains the data recieved from the server
if($('#chartBar')!=null){
        $('#chartBar').removeData();
    }
/*Function to request data to server*/
//If data recieved
 var avgCapacity = [];
   for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
      avgCapacity.push(data[i].Volume);
      $scope.modalLabels.push(data[i].Day + "/" + data[i].Month);
            }
      $scope.data.values = ([avgCapacity]);
```

[image: Second chart originated]

[image: Chart when mouse over]

This is the html behind:

```
<div ng-hide="data==0">
    <h4 id="chartTitle"><b>{{Title}}</b></h4>
<canvas id="ChartBar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-options="options"
        chart-labels="modalLabels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="series">
</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy the previous chart instance by calling `.destroy()` before you generate the new chart.